# Return once condition is true without hanging

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

So I have this computation job, that requires startng 6 threads and waiting for those to finish. The threads change a "local" variable within the class.
I want to have the function return "True" once the local variable is a certain value. However, I want to do this in a fashion where it doesn't hang the thread. So a constant "Do Loop" is not gonna work. Are there any standard ways of doing this?

```
Public Function Start(ByVal Cores As Integer) As Boolean
    For i = 0 To 10
      // Heavy work

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Compute(Core, StartInt, EndInt))

    Next

    Do // <- How to avoid checking ThreadsTerimnated = ThreadsStarted every clockcycle?
       // Threading.Sleep hangs thread.

        If ThreadsTerminated = ThreadsStarted Then
            MergeResults(Cores)
            Return True
        End If
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: You may want to know that if you need to pause a thread without hanging it, you can call `await Task.Delay()` which will stop processing for the specified milliseconds without blocking the thread there. I just included this as an FYI since you had considered pausing the thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a list of your `Tasks` and use `Tasks.WaitAll`

```
Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
For i = 0 To 10
  // Heavy work
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Compute(Core, StartInt, EndInt)))
Next

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: This answer makes no sense - `WaitAll` definitely will "hang the thread" - some explanation why it is even related to the questions would be nice.